# how to do page break after every nth product in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I need to print only ten products or lines per page in qweb. The nest ten products must be print in the second page.

Kindly help me to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Put your **custom logic** to add  10 products and after next iter  do  `page-break-after: always;`

Comment: Inside foreach loop, I'm checking t-if="o_index==4" then i had put page-break-after:always; but it does not work.